# Creating and Removing database relationships for faster performance

Tags: database-design, relational-database

My idea in relational database:

Can I create master database / main database where my table has primary keys and index using InnoDB engine and then when i finish up coding in php for the business logic

Question #1:

Can I clone the database (main) then remove their relational features like primary keys and indexes.

So that the clone will be used in production for optimized / faster transactions and the main / master will only be used for coding / development / error tracing?

So that I can only use the (main) database too for viewing database relationship diagramas using SQLYog and not in production database.

Question #2.

Is there a tool for doing this, and can i MIGRATE / Export live data from the production 
tables to the development tables. So that when conducting test's I will used live data manipulate with?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, of course you can have two tables containing the same data, but one lacking the relational features. However, your tables will go out of sync unless you update them both.

2) As mentioned, you can either update both tables when insert/removing/updating data, or have them automatically sync as soon as changes occur. I haven't ever done this myself, but you may find an answer that suits your needs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942380/how-can-i-synchronize-two-mysql-tables-that-have-same-structures-and-different-s), though that answer's specific on the tables being on different servers. I also believe SQLYog is capable of keeping tables in sync.